# Having problems placing ships in my Battleship program in C

Tags: c

I've been struggling with this for about 2 hours now. For some reason instead of placing the characters over the ~ that make up my board the characters are placed in random spots that are not the cordinates I enter. Hopefully someone canhelp guide me in the right direction.

```
void place_ships(int board[ROWS][COLS])
{

    int ship_type = 1, ship_length = 0, row = 0, col = 0, direction = 0, count = 0;

    for (ship_type = 1; ship_type < 6; ship_type++)
    {
                    if (ship_type == 1)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Carrier (5 spots).\n\n");
                        ship_length = 5;
                    }
                    else if (ship_type == 2)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Battleship (4 spots).\n\n");
                        ship_length = 4;
                    }
                    else if (ship_type == 3)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Submarine (3 spots).\n\n");
                        ship_length = 3;
                    }
                    else if (ship_type == 4)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Cruiser (3 spots).\n\n");
                        ship_length = 3;
                    }
                    else if (ship_type == 5)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Destroyer (2 spots).\n\n");
                        ship_length = 2;
                    }

        printf("Choose the direction of your ship. (0 is vertical, 1 is horizontal)\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&direction);

            printf("Please choose ROW number.\n");
            scanf("%d",&row);
            printf("Please choose COLUMN number.\n");
            scanf("%d",&col);

            if (direction == 0)
            {

                    for (count = 0; count < ship_length; count++)
                    {
                            if (ship_type == 1)
                            {
                                board[row+count][col] = 'c';
                                print_board (board, row, col);
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 2)
                            {
                                board[row+count][col] = 'b';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 3)
                            {
                                board[row+count][col] = 's';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 4)
                            {
                                board[row+count][col] = 'r';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 5)
                            {
                                board[row+count][col] = 'd';
                            }
                    }
            }

            if (direction == 1)
            {
                    for (count = 0; count < ship_length; count++)
                    {
                            if (ship_type == 1)
                            {
                                board[row][col+count] = 'c';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 2)
                            {
                                board[row][col+count] = 'b';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 3)
                            {
                                board[row][col+count] = 's';
                            }
                            else if (ship_type == 4)
                            {
                                board[row][col+count] = 'r';
                            }
                            else if(ship_type == 5)
                            {
                                board[row][col+count] = 'd';
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The print board function is:

```
void print_board (char board[ROWS][COLS], int num_rows, int num_cols)
{
    int row_index = 0, col_index = 0;

    for (row_index = 0; row_index < num_rows; row_index++)
    {
        for (col_index = 0; col_index < num_cols; col_index++)
        {
            printf ("%c ", board[row_index][col_index]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

okay so this is what I changed it to. Do I need to define a struct in my header? Again I'm a big beginner...

```
void place_ships(int board[ROWS][COLS])
{

    int ship_type = 0, ship_length = 0, row = 0, col = 0, direction = 0, count = 0;
    char * typestr[] = { "Ship type 0", "Carrier", "Battleship", "Submarine", "Cruiser", "Destroyer" };
    char* tag = "0cbsrd"; 

    for (ship_type = 0; ship_type < 6; ship_type++)
    {
        ship_length = 7 - ship_type;
        prinf("Please enter where you would like to place %s (%s) spots).\n\n",typstr[ship_type], ship_length);

        printf("Choose the direction of your ship. (0 is vertical, 1 is horizontal)\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&direction);

        printf("Please choose ROW number.\n");
        scanf("%d",&row);
        printf("Please choose COLUMN number.\n");
        scanf("%d",&col);

        if (direction == 0)
        {
            board[row+count][col] = tag[ship_type];
        }
        else
        {
            board[row][col+count] = tag[ship_type];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of generic suggestions: Instead of using *magic numbers* for ship types, use an `enum`. And instead of the big `if...else if` lists, use `switch`.

Comment: the only problem I face with that is that I am a beginner in a Cpts 121 class and i don't know what enum is. I know switches a little bit, how would I use that instead?

Comment: Also, you might want to add checks so that no coordinates are outside the board, including when placing the ships.

Comment: Better than swithc would be - in this case - calculation, `printf()` outputting and maybe array lookup. Maybe this reveals the reasons for not working better...

Comment: Argh, my eyes hurt... That's one awful coding mate... Anyway semms to work fine for me for what I can see in debugging. Maybe your problem is not in this function... Can you please share *print_board()* function?

Comment: lol yeah I realize I'm not very good. This is my 5th program ever in my class. Here's the print_board()

Comment: Be careful when mixing `char`s and `int`s. This likely will cause unexpected behaviour. Remember, they're different sizes. In fact, your `print_board(..)` used `char`s and your `place_ships(..)` used `int`s.

Comment: Also be aware that arrays with a dynamic number of columns must be treated differently. With the parameter declaration `char board[ROWS][COLS]`, you assume the given number of columns (and rows, but that doesn't matter). If it is really flexible, you should declare it as 1D array and calculate the offset yourself with `row_index * num_cols + col_index`. This holds for both functions. BTW: In your 2nd version, you have forgotten to put your `print_board()` call.

Comment: I declared ROWS and COLS in my header as 10 each, sorry for not stating that earlier

Comment: Or use #define SOMETHING 78 if you don't know what enums are.

Comment: i found my mistake. other than "awful coding"... i changed void place_ships(int board[ROWS][COLS]) to a char board[ROWS]COLS] and it prints to my board now!!!

Answer (score 2):

I see a few potential problems that may screw it up for you:

scanf is a bit tricky since it will also leave the newline char in the buffer after reading out the number. You may want to use fgets() instead to read from the keyboard, then use sscanf on the string to extract the number (or atoi).

when you write into the matrix you need to make sure the ship fits so after the user has entered the coordinate and the direction you need to check if the ship fits e.g.

```
if ( direction == vertical )
{
  ok = ( row + ship_length < ROWS ) // assuming row index [0, ROWS-1]
}
else 
{
  ok = ( col + ship_length < COLS )
}
```

and yes like somebody else already mentioned please use enums for constant values 
e.g.

```
enum directions { vertical, horizontal };
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple switch statement instead of the if-else list:

```
switch (ship_type)
{
case 1:
    board[row+count][col] = 'c';
    break;
case 2:
    board[row+count][col] = 'b';
    break;
case 3:
    board[row+count][col] = 's';
    break;
case 4:
    board[row+count][col] = 'r';
    break;
case 5:
    board[row+count][col] = 'd';
    break;
}
```

Actually, a better solution might be like this:

```
char ship_symbols[] = { 'c', 'b', 's', 'r', 'd' };
board[row+count][col] = ship_symbols[ship_type - 1];  /* -1 because array indexes start at 0 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Some improvement suggestions:

- don't use `if()` stuff if you can calculate something.

  I.e., instead of

  ```
                  if (ship_type == 1)
                  {
                      printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Carrier (5 spots).\n\n");
                      ship_length = 5;
                  }
                                  ...
                  else if (ship_type == 5)
                  {
                      printf("Please enter where you would like to place your Destroyer (2 spots).\n\n");
                      ship_length = 2;
                  }
  ```

  better use

  ```
  ship_length = 7 - ship_type;
  printf("Please enter where you would like to place your %s (%s spots).\n\n", typestr[ship_type], ship_length);
  ```

  provided you have defined somewhere

  ```
   char * typestr[] = { "Ship type 0", "Carrier", "Battleship", "Submarine", "Cruiser", "Destroyer" };
  ```

  and instead of

  ```
  if (ship_type == 1)
  {
      board[row+count][col] = 'c';
      print_board (board, row, col);
  }
  ...
  ```

  use

  ```
  if (direction == 0) {
      board[row+count][col] = tag[ship_type];
  } else {
      board[row][col+count] = tag[ship_type];
  }
  print_board (board, row, col);
  ```

  with

  ```
  char* tag = "0cbsrd";
  ```
- Add some output after reading in the data. This shows you if you really have read the correct data.
- Are your array boundaries correct?

Comment: can the char * typestr[] = { "Ship type 0", "Carrier", "Battleship", "Submarine", "Cruiser", "Destroyer" };  be defined in the function or does it have to be in the header?

Comment: In the function would be ok, but then with `static`. If not, it would be rebuild with every function call, what would be not s good.

Comment: i have no been taught what static is yet, but typestr is a struct right?

Comment: No, it is an array of char pointers. Each of them points to a zero-terminated string.